# Why is my bootstrap grid system not working?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, grid, frontend

I don't get why my grid system is not being displayed as expected.

Html code:

```
<header class="navbar navbar-dark navbar-expand bd-navbar bg-dark p-0 shadow">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-3 text-sm-center text-md-center text-lg-left">
            <a class="navbar-brand"><!-- img src is django code, ignore it-->
                <img src="{% static 'images/logo.jpg' %}" class="rounded-circle" style="height:30px;width:30px;">
                <label style="font-family: 'Oswald', 'DejaVu Sans Mono' !important; color:white;">Title</label>
            </a>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-9 text-sm-center text-md-center text-lg-left">
            <!--my form here-->
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

The important thing is the `lg` allingment here. You can see how I have a `div` with 12 cols, which has two `div`s inside, one with 3 cols and the other with 9 (so they make 12 in addition). The expected is to see them as explained in [Grid system - Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/). But the result I'm getting is...

[image: =)]

Why???!!!
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your *col* `<div>`s should be placed inside *row* `<div>`s as follows:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-9"></div>
  <div class="col-3"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! How can I make if I only want `row` class to work in `lg` but not in other sizes?

Comment: Row needs to work on every sub divs, it's the best practice. You also need to place your row inside a div class container or container-fluid

Comment: But sometimes you can't know where a row ends, since it depends on the screen size (sm, md, lg, etc). How do you handle it? Does it has any documentation?

Comment: the `row` will have the size of the elements in contains. That's why you are using the `col` inside, to manage the behaviour of the differents `div` inside the `row`